# problem loading site dlls from the GAC

Tags: gac

I have about 70 sites on a server that all use the same dlls.  I thought it would be better to register them in the GAC and remove them from the site's bin folder so they're all looking at one place.  My understanding is that if a dll that the site requires isn't found in the bin directory that asp then looks for it in the GAC.  I've strong named all the dlls and registered them in the GAC but when I removed the dlls from one of the sites to test it it ended up giving me the error that it couldn't load the type found in one of the dlls.  Is there something else I need to do to make asp look in the GAC if it's not in the bin directory or is my understanding of how that works incorrect?  Thanks.

Comment: I've figured this out that I had to add the assembly references to the machine.config file.  But of the main reasons I wanted to move the dlls was in hopes that by having the dlls in one place I would get a performance boost.  In discussing this with a co-worker they seemed to think I'd actually get a bit of a performance hit.  Does anyone know if this will help or hurt performance by putting the dlls in the gac?  Thanks.